# How to get on a single page different links based on css

Tags: html, css

Perhaps a simple question.
I want to keep a single style.css to put al my formatting in for a website.
I want some links (not all the links!) to behave different, as those links should not be underlined.
Also they require different font settings (larger and different colors)
This code works inside an HTML to remove the link underline:

```
<a style=" text-decoration:none;" href="News.html">
```

I would like to use something like

```
<a class="nounderline" href="news.html">
```

And then put al my settings into it, but i am unsure on how to write it in the central style.css file
i dont know how to handle hoover and visited colors, not sure how to write it down, could someone explain how to write such a CSS so that it wont affect all hyperlinks ?

Comment: classes and pseudoclasses. `.style1 { }` `.style2 { }`. `a.style1:hover { }` ...

Comment: thats a part i dont understand, how would i write it down in a sentral style.css file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your css like this:

```
a { color: #0f0; }

a.special { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #00f; 
}

a:hover {
    color: #0ff;
}

a.special:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #ff0;
}
```

In your HTML, you declare all normal anchors as is. But, provide class `special` to those anchors you want to be treated specially.

Comment: for a.special how would you write down how it behaves with hoover ?

Comment: that seams to be the syntax i was looking for, thanks

Comment: No because `a` is a tag, but `special` is a class. So `a.special` means an anchor with the special class applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different classes to the two types of links you want to create and have your CSS deal differently with the two classes. For the second example you can set the style for a link of class `nounderline` using:

```
a.nounderline {
  ... style ... 
}
```

To set the style for a given class(say `nounderline` like above) when you hover you can do:

```
a.nounderline:hover {
  ... style when hovered ... 
}
```

Comment: could you provide a sample of how that would look like in a css file ?

Comment: @user613326 I believe I just have. Please take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [w3 article on selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

A class helps identify (select) an element in CSS, you can then build these into your selectors adding increasing degrees of specificity, e.g.

```
a{
 /*would target all links */
}
.nounderline{
 /*would target anything with the nounderline class */
}
a.nounderline{
 /*would only target links with the nounderline class */
}
```

Once you've build your selectors, you can then use pseudo selectors to target specific actions, e.g. `:active`, `:hover`

```
a.nounderline:hover{
 /*would only target links with the nounderline class which are hovered over */
}
a.nounderline:visited{
 /*would only target links with the nounderline class which have been visited */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add classes to the links.

For example in HTML:

```
<a class="nounderline" href="#link">Link</a>
```

In CSS:

```
.nounderline{ text-decoration:none; }
```

So each  tag you provide the "nounderline" with, won't have underlined text.

Answer (score -1):

you can still use pseudo classes like this:

```
a:link    {color: blue}
a:visited    {color: purple}
a:active    {color: red}
```

even with `.nounderline`

```
a.nounderline:link    {color: blue}
a.nounderline:visited    {color: purple}
a.nounderline:active    {color: red}
```